# What is noun-word or any expression used for "bits of food spilt unto the ground out of the plate"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns

I am an English language learner in need help from especially native English speakers. Please, I am looking for a noun-word or any expression used for "bits of food spilt unto the ground out of the plate, by children while eating especially when they are eating carelessly". In my native Hausa language we say "birbidin-abinci''. I wanted to say in English to some children to clean up the mess after they finished eating (the mess = birbidin-abinci).

I looked for it using the expression in quotes on "www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary", but the tool did not give me what I needed. Thank you in anticipation of your assistance.

Comment: I don't think there is a word for this.  An irritated parent might say:  "Stop making a mess!", but that can cover a lot of things that children do.  Another thing  parents might say is "Mind your manners!", which again isn't specific to eating.  The closest I can think of is the reminder:  "Table manners!"

Comment: What is the word or phrase in your native language? Also, can you give a sentence (with blank) that uses the word you want?

Comment: In my native Hausa language we say "birbidin-abinci''.  I wanted to say in English to some children to clean up the mess after they finished eating (the mess = birbidin-abinci). Thanks to Sumelic above for suggesting the word "mess".

Comment: "Scraps" is a good word for bits of food. "Crumbs" can also be used, but it typically refers to bits of baked foods that can crumble, like cookies, crackers, cakes, or breads. "Stop making a mess!", as @ab2 suggested, is probably what a parent is most likely to say to a child who is spilling bits of food.

Comment: @Sumelic and shosht. Thanks for the useful information it is really helpful.

Comment: @iandu76: I'm glad for any help I could provide, but in this case all I did was edit your post to make sure your question explained everything you said in the comments.  ab2 is the one who suggested the word "mess". Just so you know, Stack Exchange only lets you send a comment to one person: I was notified of your previous comment (because you wrote "@sumelic") but shosht was not

Answer (score 3):

1. Crumbs

> 'Even the dogs eat the crumbs which fall from their Master's table.'
>   Matthew 15:27 (Authorised Version 1611)

2. Scraps

> https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scrap

Comment: Although *crumbs* can fall off tables, they're not the only kind of food remains that can do so.

Comment: @Lawrence the word crumb has a wider meaning than just breadcrumb - see edit

Comment: Let me know once you've posted the edit, and I'll take a look.

Comment: @Lawrence Edit posted now.

Comment: That still doesn't work. Definition 2 "A very small amount of something" refers to a metaphorical usage, as the examples demonstrate - e.g. crumbs of *support*. It doesn't apply to non-crumbly, literal *somethings* such as ice cream.

Comment: @Lawrence Edited again 'scraps'

Comment: That's better, but doesn't indicate that they have fallen off the plate. I think the OP's term *mess* works better.

Comment: @Lawrence and others.  Thanks for the useful information it is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think "crumbs" serves the purpose you want.  Most specifically "crumbs" come from bread or crackers or other baked things, but "clean up the crumbs" could certainly be used more broadly.

Comment: It wouldn't work with non-crumbly foods such as spaghetti, tomato sauce, soup, or even peas and the like.

Comment: @Jackie Hoffman. Please can you suggest another word for other food types (non-crumbly) like the Spaghetti, ......., or even rice. I am interested in your consideration.

Comment: I agree that "scraps" is good.  You could say "clean up the scraps."  That could apply to little spilled bits of anything -- food, wood shavings, cloth, etc.  Not liquids, though.  For liquid you might say "spill" or "spots" or "drips."

Answer (score -1):

" Tesuk " My food in my plate have completely fallen from my plate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is this a word you use in *English*? Can you give any examples in a sentence?